# Why is system load average around 9 on login?

Tags: login, cpu-load

I check my start up applications, disable them, but login take a long time and **System Load** is very high *(about 9)*.

this only happens on default user account, and I have this problem since **10.10 upgrading**.
what should be wrong? :-/

---

#### edit:

I made an sh file and set it to run at startup.
I pasted them in pastebin.com, [dmesg output](http://pastebin.com/aE5Z5Sju), [top output](http://pastebin.com/Zsy3XC72)

Comment: What does `top` show for output? What things are still running when you check?

Comment: for about 40 second I cannot run anything! I added *top* output to Question description

Comment: You need to post the list of processes, not only the top header.

Comment: For a system with such a high load average the cpu utilisation is very low. Please post the rest of top.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked `dmesg` output too? When system load average does not match the number of running processes (7 vs 2 in your example), that would indicate that something is waiting on disk I/O. Usually this is network related for network filesystems.